# WordPress Custom Posts Page Not Displaying

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have just encountered a small but weird problem in WordPress. I have made page called 'nyheter' (translates to news in Norwegian), where I have made a custom page having a 'page-nyheter.php' in my template folder where I want to display all the posts on the website.

Please keep in mind that I don't want to display any posts on my front page.

I do also have a custom static front page that is just 'front-page.php' which works fine navigating to. However, choosing my front page as the homepage, and the 'nyheter' page as the posts page in the settings, ends up showing the homepage on the 'nyheter' page as well. All of the other pages works fine, and if I just remove the 'nyheter' page from the custom posts page, it works fine again.

What exactly am I doing wrong here? Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Posts page will use `index.php` for it's template, and the Static Front Page will use `front-page.php`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Is the Nyheter page powered by posts? Why not use index.php since is most suitable for posts than a page template.

https://wphierarchy.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you are a developer please enable wp_debug to true. Then check your errors.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that I get this message when I go to my front page and my news page: 8iSm_SvEGvS.js:62 ErrorUtils caught an error: "<![EX[["Tried to listen to element of type %s from %s: %s","click","Error","C...". Subsequent errors won't be logged; see https://fburl.com/debugjs.. Do you know what this could possibly mean?

Comment: I sent the console output, it was not a link. I have this project locally on my machine.

Comment: I think it's JS problem, please paste the screenshot of it.

Comment: I really doubt that's the issue, as I literally have no custom JavaScript code.